# Play framework's sbt import maven module error

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, maven-3

I am using Playframework 2.5.4 to serve as REST API endpoint in default sbt build, compile & run with activator.

This play module imports a `core` module in local maven (3.9), where types were defined.  Such as:

```
package com.myCompany

case class User(
   id: Option[UUID] = None,  
   username: String  
)
```

Then play `controller` package will import `com.myCompany.User`.

Issue is, when activator compiles, it gives `unknown parameter name: username`

If I placed `case class` in play's `models` package, it compiles without error.

Below is my build.sbt

```
name := """api"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  ws,
  filters,
  "com.myCompany" % "core" % "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
)

routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases",
  Resolver.mavenLocal
//  "Local Maven Repository" at "file:///home/pocheng/.m2/repository"
)
```

I suspect build.sbt file is having issue.  Would appreciate any pointer.  Thanks.

Comment: did you reload before building?

Comment: It seems you need to update your `core` component in your maven local repository (`mvn clean install `)

Comment: Did `mvn clean install`.  Same error.